# Array Project int double mismatch

Tags: java, arrays, int, double, mismatch

I have an array project that I need a bit of help with. I have most of it done but I've run into a couple problems towards the end. I have the ability to put in Student Names, Grades, and then have the grades sorted (along with the names) and printed in descending order. I need the grades set as Doubles though, and they are currently stuck as Ints. I've tried to change the instances of Int to Double, but I get a mismatch error. I also have it set so I input the size of the array at the beginning, but it's asking me for the "Number of Students" twice. How do I fix this so it'll only ask one time, or have 1 input for both answers. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        {
            Scanner GradeIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner NameIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print( "How many students are there? " );
            int[]GradeArray = new int[GradeIn.nextInt()];
            String[]nameArray = new String[GradeIn.nextInt()];

            for( int i=0 ; i<GradeArray.length ; i++ ) 
            {
                System.out.println( "Enter Grade for Student " + (i+1) + ": " );
                GradeArray[i] = GradeIn.nextInt();
                System.out.println( "Enter Name of Student " + (i+1) + ": " );
                nameArray[i] = NameIn.nextLine();
            }

            bubbleSort(GradeArray, nameArray);


            for (int i = 0; i<GradeArray.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(nameArray[i]);
                System.out.print(": ");
                System.out.print(GradeArray[i] + "   ");

            }
        }
    }

    private static void bubbleSort(int[]GradeArray, String[] nameArray){

        int n = GradeArray.length;
        int temp = 0;
        String temp2;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<(n-i);j++){

                if(GradeArray[j-1]<GradeArray[j]){
                    //swap
                    temp=GradeArray[j-1];
                    GradeArray[j-1]=GradeArray[j];
                    GradeArray[j]=temp;

                    temp2=nameArray[j-1];
                    nameArray[j-1]=nameArray[j];
                    nameArray[j]=temp2;


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any possibility of having a 2D array that stores name and grade for each student as the input and then sort it out? Why not define a variant array so you can save any data type...

Comment: He's requested that we have 2 Arrays. One for Names, one for Grades.

Comment: Rather than entering the number of students to start, it's usually better to check for 'q' or 'quit' when processing the input so you can just start entering students until you type 'quit'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the following lines must be replaced:

```
int[]GradeArray = new int[GradeIn.nextInt()];
GradeArray[i] = GradeIn.nextInt();
private static void bubbleSort(int[]GradeArray, String[] nameArray){
```

with:

```
double[]GradeArray = new double[GradeIn.nextInt()];
GradeArray[i] = GradeIn.nextDouble();
private static void bubbleSort(double[]GradeArray, String[] nameArray){
```

If it doesn't work after replacing those, it might be helpful to post how you changed it as well.

For the asking for number of students twice problem, change:

```
int[]GradeArray = new int[GradeIn.nextInt()];
String[]nameArray = new String[GradeIn.nextInt()];
```

to:

```
int count = GradeIn.nextInt();
int[]GradeArray = new int[count];
String[]nameArray = new String[count];
```